# How to Attach a C Program executable to a Keyboard Key

Tags: linux, hotkeys

OS: GNU/Linux

I have a program: hello.c

Executable: hello

Required:

The executable "hello" is not running.

I press Key "F1".

The executable "hello" automatically runs & produces the ouput (if any).

Please guide me on how to achieve this.

Comment: Are you logged into a local console? Or are you at the local console but not logged in? Or is this supposed to work remotely? Your question is very, very vague.

Comment: I am working on my local console. I just want to execute this code by pressing a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/4200800/477035

> You can determine the character sequence emitted by a key by pressing `Ctrl-v` at the command line, then pressing the key you're
>   interested in. On my system for F12, I get `^[[24~`. The `^[` represents
>   Esc. Different types of terminals or terminal emulators can emit
>   different codes for the same key.
>
> At a Bash prompt you can enter a command like this to enable the key macro so you can try it out.
>
> ```
> bind '"\e[24~":"foobar"'
> ```
>
> Now, when you press F12, you'll get "foobar" on the command line ready for further 
>   editing. If you wanted a keystroke to enter a
>   command immediately, you can add a newline:
>
> ```
> bind '"\e[24~":"pwd\n"'
> ```

The man page for bash contains this

```
   bind [-m keymap] -x keyseq:shell-command
   bind [-m keymap] keyseq:function-name
```

If your shell is not bash, I suggest scrutinizing the man page for your preferred shell for equivalent capability.